# Is there a way to summarise or list all current PyLint errors, with sublime (or otherwise)?

Tags: python, sublimetext, pylint

Is there an option to list all current PyLint errors I have in my project, with sublime, *using the [Pylinter](https://github.com/biermeester/Pylinter) plugin* or otherwise?

Here is an example, of similar functionality, in eclipse:

[image]

Comment: Are you using any of the `pylint` plug-ins (e.g. [`Pylinter`](https://github.com/biermeester/Pylinter))?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes I am. Forgot that `PyLint != pylinter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `anaconda_linter_show_errors_on_save` option in the [Anaconda](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda) plugin for Sublime Text 3 which shows the error/warning list upon saving.

The same window can be opened opening the command search window and searching for "Anaconda: Show error list".

[image: Anaconda error list]

There's also a [Flake8Lint](https://github.com/dreadatour/Flake8Lint) plugin for both Sublime Text 2/3, which is able to display the error list on file saving:

```
// popup a dialog of detected conditions?
"popup": true,
```

But there's no menu option in Flake8Lint to display the errors on a command - it is able to display errors on file saving for now.

Comment: Is this an alternative to Pylinter? And is it compatible with Sublime2?

Comment: @Pureferret Anaconda is more of an alternative for [SublimePythonIDE](https://github.com/JulianEberius/SublimePythonIDE), it has a linter (PyLint), PEP8/PyFlakes/McCabe checkers, better autocompletion and whatnot.

Comment: When I go to Install Package and Type in Anaconda, or  SublimePythonIDE, nothing comes up. What aren't I getting?

Comment: @Pureferret Sorry, it seems that they're not compatible with Sublime Text 2. Although, there is a [Flake8Lint](https://github.com/dreadatour/Flake8Lint) plugin that is supported in ST2, it pops up the error list upon saving.